# SubView added to View but not showing

Tags: swift, addsubview

I'm trying to show a subview that has been added to a view, but it does not show up when the button is pressed.

I have tried setting isOpaque to 1, alpha to 1, isHidden to false (without needing to press the button) and have checked that I have run view.addSubview(). I have also found out that the subview is not hidden at all but the background is white (it is supposed to be blue or red).

code to add subviews

```swift
//setup
viewBGKRect = CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 984, height: 660)
viewBGK = UIView(frame: viewBGKRect)
viewBGK.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 139.0, green: 206.0, blue: 231.0, alpha: 1.0)
viewBGK.alpha = 1
viewBGK.isOpaque = true

viewRGKRect = CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 984, height: 660)
viewRGK = UIView(frame: viewRGKRect)
viewRGK.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 240.0, green: 177.0, blue: 187.0, alpha: 1.0)
viewRGK.alpha = 1
viewRGK.isOpaque = true

//isHidden is set to false when the buttons are pressed
viewBGK.isHidden = true
viewRGK.isHidden = true

view.addSubview(viewBGK)
view.addSubview(viewRGK)
```

code to show subviews

```swift
@IBAction func goalkeeper(_ sender: UIButton) {
        switch sender.tag {
        case 0:
            // blue
            viewBGK.isHidden = false
            viewRGK.isHidden = true
            return
        default:
            viewBGK.isHidden = true
            viewRGK.isHidden = false
            return
        }
    }
```

I expect a blue/red rectangle to appear at the top of the screen but it does not show.

Comment: Where did you put "code to add subviews"? `viewDidLoad`? Also, what view does not show? The blue or the red or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind I found the answer:
UIColor RGB is from 0-1 not 0-255 the colors should be

(blue)

```swift
UIColor(red:0.55, green:0.81, blue:0.91, alpha:1.0)
```

and

(red)

```swift
UIColor(red:0.94, green:0.69, blue:0.73, alpha:1.0)
```

not

(blue)

```swift
UIColor(red: 139.0, green: 206.0, blue: 231.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

and

(red)

```swift
UIColor(red: 240.0, green: 177.0, blue: 187.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

i feel really dumb now.

Comment: You did an awesome job finding the answer yourself. Here's another way to get colors without having to do all the math to get a decimal: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kTiL4Xtwg84

Comment: well done, on finding the solution to your question. If it works you should mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to utilize custom colors, it might be easier to declare them somewhere other than in a view controller. One approach would be to declare them in an extension. To do this, you would do the following:

1. Create a new Swift file and name it `UIColor+Extension.swift`
2. Inside the new file, add the following code:

   ```
   extension UIColor {
       static var customBlue: UIColor {
           return #colorLiteral(red: 0.5450980392, green: 0.8078431373, blue: 0.9058823529, alpha: 1)
       }

       static var customRed: UIColor {
           return #colorLiteral(red: 0.9411764706, green: 0.6941176471, blue: 0.7333333333, alpha: 1)
       }
   }
   ```

I didn't type those colors out. I simply typed `return Color Literal` and it showed a white rounded rectangle. When I clicked on the rectangle, I saw this:

[image]

Then, I clicked the "Other" button and I typed in the RGB values:

[image]

Lastly, you want to avoid writing repetitive code (DRY = don't repeat yourself). Here's the updated code:

```
//setup
viewBGKRect = CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 984, height: 660)
viewBGK = UIView(frame: viewBGKRect)
viewBGK.backgroundColor = .customBlue

viewRGKRect = CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 984, height: 660)
viewRGK = UIView(frame: viewRGKRect)
viewRGK.backgroundColor = .customRed

[viewBGK, viewRGK].forEach { view in
    view.alpha = 1
    view.isOpaque = true
    //isHidden is set to false when the buttons are pressed
    view.isHidden = true
}
```